# Baguette Box not working with AmazonS3 URL when there is no file extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, lightbox

I started using AmazonS3 to store files and images and I noticed that Baguette Box stopped working because the AmazonS3 image URL didn't contain the file extension (like .jpg), only the file key.

I guess Baguette Box doesn't recognize it as a image automatically because of the missing image extension and when I click on the link the image is being opened in the way without using Baguette Box.

I'm just using the code below to call Baguette Box:

```
baguetteBox.run('#PhotoContainer');
```

URL example:

```
https://mybucket-com.s3.amazonaws.com/1bf8e7a2-a7ca-49ca-ab52-086ead4aa46e
```

Does anybody know how to make it work without extension (including the extension on the file Key is not an option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received an answer how to make it work on the github's issue below:

[Baguette Box not working with AmazonS3 URL when there is no file extension](https://github.com/feimosi/baguetteBox.js/issues/145)

The solution is including a filter considering part of amazon URL, and that's worked fine as example below:

```
baguetteBox.run('#PhotoContainer', {  filter: /.*amazonaws.*/i });
```

Or could be used a filter to consider all a tags like:

```
baguetteBox.run('#PhotoContainer', { filter: /.*/i });
```